# Rails Capistrano precompile assets locally not loading on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

i deployed my rails app to the AWS server and tried running the rake assets:precompile locally and uploading on deploy .due to the out of memory issue on the server ,

this is my **deploy.rb**

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock '3.5.0'

set :application, 'fullpower_tee'
set :repo_url, 'git_repo' # Edit this to match your repository
set :branch, :master
set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/fullpower_tee'
set :pty, true
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/application.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system public/uploads}
set :keep_releases, 2
set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_ruby_version, 'ruby-2.2.1'


set :puma_rackup, -> { File.join(current_path, 'config.ru') }
set :puma_state, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_bind, "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/puma.sock"    #accept array for multi-bind
set :puma_conf, "#{shared_path}/puma.rb"
set :puma_access_log, "#{shared_path}/log/puma_error.log"
set :puma_error_log, "#{shared_path}/log/puma_access.log"
set :puma_role, :app
set :puma_env, fetch(:rack_env, fetch(:rails_env, 'production'))
set :puma_threads, [0, 8]
set :puma_workers, 0
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true
set :puma_preload_app, false


namespace :deploy do
  namespace :assets do

    Rake::Task['deploy:assets:precompile'].clear_actions

    desc 'Precompile assets locally and upload to servers'
    task :precompile do
      on roles(fetch(:assets_roles)) do
        run_locally do
          with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
            execute 'bin/rake assets:precompile'
          end
        end

        within release_path do
          with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
            old_manifest_path = "#{shared_path}/public/assets/manifest*"
            execute :rm, old_manifest_path if test "[ -f #{old_manifest_path} ]"
            upload!('./public/assets/', "#{shared_path}/public/", recursive: true)
          end
        end

        run_locally { execute 'rm -rf public/assets' }
      end
    end

  end
end

namespace :deploy do

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end

end
```

and my **config/environments/production.rb**

```
  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css *.js )

  # Add the fonts path
  config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"

  # Precompile additional assets
  config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )
  config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js )
  config.assets.precompile += [ 'admin.css',
                                'bootstrap.css',
                                'dark-red-theme.css',
                                'style.css',
                                'jquery.growl.css',
                                'default-theme.css',
                                'font-awesome.css',
                                'jquery.simpleLens.css',
                                'jquery.smartmenus.bootstrap.css',
                                'nouislider.css',
                                'sequence-theme.modern-slide-in.css',
                                'slick.css',
                                'admin/app.css',
                                'admin/cart.css',
                                'admin/foundation.css',
                                'admin/normalize.css',
                                'admin/help.css',
                                'admin/ie.css',
                                'autocomplete.css',
                                'application.css',
                                'foundation.css',
                                'home_page.css',
                                'login.css',
                                'markdown.css',
                                'myaccount.css',
                                'normalize.css',
                                'pikachoose_product.css',
                                'product_page.css',
                                'products_page.css',
                                'shopping_cart_page.css',
                                'signup.css',
                                'site/app.css',
                                'sprite.css',
                                'tables.css',
                                'cupertino/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css',# in vendor
                                'scaffold.css' # in vendor
                                ]
```

and my application.rb has

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

the capistrano deploy is successfully able to precompile assets locally and then uploading it to the shared/public directory , but i cannot see the assets loading on my website , been stuck in this issue since a day Please help !

this is my browser log
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

Given that your URLs are 404ing, and it doesnt show like the requests contain the hashes, you need to be sure to use stylesheet_link_tag in your layout/view files to load css files. As well as use the various asset helpers in the css itself for background images.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets

<s>Capistrano deploys from git. You can configure it to pull from a local repo, if you dont want to push up shared assets to your github, but regardless the assets need to be in source control.</s>

```
set :repo_url, 'file:///path/to/repo/.git'
```

To set it to a local repository.

If you absolutely dont want to store compiled changes in your git repo at all, you could run a `scp` command after the `rake assets:precompile` finishes.

```
execute 'scp -r public/assets/* user@serverip:/var/www/apps/yourapppath/shared/public/assets/*'
```

Have it point to the correct spot of course.

I'd also like to think your could optimize your assets a bit by having a few manifest files, rather than the 30 files you have in you precompile list.

Comment: i can see the precompiled assets in my shared folder on the server .. then why would i need to copy the assets from local ?

Comment: Ah, sorry I misread your original post, was thinking you were having trouble with it getting on the server. Are the assets just resulting in a 404? Can you try the path based on the files in capistrano? Do the files have read permission for public?

Comment: this is the permission for assets files '-rw-rw-r--' and this is the permission for the assets folder 'drwxrwxr-x' 

i have this in my nginx default file 
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  root /home/deploy/fullpower_tee/shared/public;

 .....

Comment: and yes i am getting the 404 not found for the assets files 

for e.g 
http://website_url/stylesheets/bootstrap.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I realize that's an example, but you are checking the files with the md5 hash in them correct? `application-9158192b73777360795514768f5d195f.css` for example

Comment: i have attached the snapshot of the browser log in the question.. i guess the javascript is loading because i got the console.log output.. but getting all these 404 not found

Comment: please see the snapshot of the browser log

Comment: That looks like to me you're not using the stylesheet_link_tag helper in your views. If you're specifying the files by path, it won't work in production. This goes for image urls in the css as well. Can see how it's done here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets

Comment: yes you are right .. i needed to include application.css stylesheet link tag
,  You can edit your answer so that i can tick it correct :)